# What type of database is suited for realtime aggregated operations on millions of rows

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, teradata, rdbms

I need to store 15-30 millions of rows of data. Most of the queries will be group by operations (aggregations). I'm currently using Teradata as the database backend. But the response time is not real-time (some queries are taking about 30 seconds). I was looking into Cassandra as a substitute but in some documentation, I found that if there are group by operations, then Cassandra is not the best option.

What database would be most suited for my use case given that a maximum of 100 users will use the application at a time (along with data updates happening in parallel)? Any traditional RDBMS can handle this kind of requirements?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should run a skew factor analysis on your tables, as 30M is a very low data volume to be handled by Teradata. You might also look into join indexes if you run extensive joins for your aggregate runs. How many nodes are in your cluster? And don't forget to collect stats specific to your queries (using diag helpstats).

Comment: There are a lot of things to look at when it comes to addressing your concerns with performance in Teradata. Ravioli and Access_Granted have touched on some of them. The absence of knowing your physical data model, queries, and to some extent the configuration of your environment makes your question broad. If you need tactical query performance, then you physical data model (including any indexes), queries, and existing statistics will be vital to helping you. There is also a workload management component that comes into play as well, but secondary to the other details.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra itself is not so good for aggregation, consider Cassandra + Storm/Spark

Answer (score 0):

Teradata is designed to handle very large datasets with parallelism in mind and should scale mostly linearly.  In other words, add more horsepower to your resource-bound queries and get better performance.

What bottlenecks do you have with your current 30-second queries?  Can you post a sample query with an EXPLAIN to look at?  It could be that a quick optimization will speed it up -- STATISTICs, index selection, join indexes, PPI (table partitioning), etc.